# Different Memory-need in case of using "const" and "#define" in IAR

Tags: c, memory, c-preprocessor, iar

**case 1:**
 Defining all constants as preprocessor definition using `#define` like:

```
  #define  x          12
```

Memory usage (from `file_name.lst`)

```
 2 240 bytes of CODE memory
   920 bytes of DATA memory
```

**case 2:**
 Defining all constants as compiler definition using `const unsigned int` like:

```
  const unsigned int x = 12;
```

Memory usage (from `file_name.lst`)

```
 2 240 bytes of CODE memory
     1 byte  of CONST memory
   920 bytes of DATA memory
```

**My Questions:**
Where are preprocessor definitions saved? Flash, RAM, somewhere else?
Does it mean that preprocessor definition is a way to decrease memory-usage?

Comment: Preprocessor macros do not exist at runtime anymore, so it is not saved anywhere. The `12` will be hardcoded in your executable.

Comment: "hard coded in [...]", i. e. they are actually hidden in the CODE memory section, e. g. in instructions corresponding to assembler code like `add eax, 12`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor definitions are resolved by the preprocessor. That means the preprocessor will replace every occurance of the defined name (i.e. `x`) in your source code by the defined value (i.e. 12). 
The preprocessor runs before the compiler (hence the name preprocessor). During compile time and run time there is no more x, the compile just sees the 12 in places where you wrote x.

Answer (score 1):

All numbers must be stored somewhere - you cannot allocate numbers in thin air. The amount of memory used will be the same no matter which method you use. However, you might get tricked into thinking there's a difference, either by memory segment names or by optimizer settings.

In case you use the pre-processor, they get embedded into the machine code if they are used by the program (segment name `.text`, or CODE in your case).  Just typing `#define x 12` without using `x` in the program, will mean that the value isn't stored anywhere since it isn't used.

If you declare it a `const` is will end up either in a read-only data segment (`.rodata` or similar name) or on the stack, depending on scope. It might get allocated even if the variable is not used, depending on compiler optimizer settings.

Both code and read-only data segments will be stored in flash on a microcontroller.